# He estado estudiando JavaScript viendométodo por método de cada uno de los objetos, el inconveniente viene con el método copywithin

Tags: javascript, array

buen día, como digo en el enunciado, estoy estudiando JavaScript a profundidad, y me decidí a ver método por método de cada uno de los objetos, ahora mismo me encuentro en el objeto compuesto `'Array'`, el inconveniente que tengo ahora mismo es con el método `Array.prototype.copyWithin()`, no logro entender como funciona este, es decir, he buscado en miles de páginas, en inglés y español y no lo logran explicar de manera adecuada para un novato; esto es lo que concluí, pero supongo y sé que no está del todo bien:

```
//Array.prototype.copyWithin()
// Este método copia parte de un Array para pegarlo en otra parte del mismo sin modificar su longitud, es decir,
// siempre tendrá el mismo número de valores.
//EJ: NO SÉ SI ENTENDÍ DEL TODO.

const array1 = ['Manzana', 'Pera', 'Guayaba', 'Melocotón', 'Uvas', 'Moras', 'Banano', 'Durazno', 'Mango'];
console.log(array1.copyWithin(4));  //--> Empieza desde 0 hasta el número anterior al propuesto (como si se contara desde 1) y cuando termina, se reinicia desde el valor 0.
console.log(array1.copyWithin(4,1)); //--> Realiza de igual forma la acción anterior, pero en vez de reiniciarse desde el valor 0, se reinicia desde el 1, hasta que corran otros 4 valores y ahí se reinicia por completo.
console.log(array1.copyWithin(4,1,6)); //--> Realiza de igual forma las dos anteriores acciones, pero esta vez en vez de reiniciarse luego de cumplir el segundo parámetro, lo que hace este tercero es coje como indice 0 el segundo parametro y de ahí cuenta 6, en este caso, luego de hacer esto, se reinicia.
```

Agradecería si uno de ustedes lo explica de manera más adecuada para alguien que está empezando. Mil gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como dices, el método 'copyWithin' copia una parte del array en otra parte del mismo array sin modificar su longitud.
Para una explicación más completa veamos sus parámetros:
`copyWithin(target, start, end)`

- **Target**: El índice al que vamos a copiar la secuencia. (El primer elemento del array sería el índice 0 y así sucesivamente).
- **Start** (Opcional): El comienzo de la secuencia que deseamos copiar. Su valor por defecto será 0, en caso de que no se incluya como parámetro.
- **End** (Opcional): El final de la secuencia que deseamos copiar. Su valor por defecto será la longitud del array, en caso de que no se incluya como parámetro.

Vamos a empezar por el ejemplo más sencillo:

```
const array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(array1.copyWithin(4)) //=== array1.copyWithin(4,0,6)
// Resultado: [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1]
```

En este caso, la función copia en la posición 4 y siguientes: los valores desde el índice 0 (valor por defecto de 'start') hasta el 6 (la longitud del array). Como solo existen 2 posiciones a partir del índice 4, solo se copian los 2 primeros valores del array.

Un ejemplo más complejo sería el siguiente:

```
const array1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(array1.copyWithin(4,2,3))
// Resultado: [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 5]
```

En este caso, copiamos en la posición 4 los valores que se encuentren entre la posición 2 y la 3, sin incluir esta última. Por tanto, el único valor que copiaremos será el 2. Es por ello, que la posición 5, no se ve modificada.

Más info: [Documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin)